# Windows Network Routing

Tags: windows, networking, routes

is it possible to add a route from PC2  to a network which is hosted by PC1 to reach a webserver in the second network?

This is my setup:

PC1 Network1 - 10.0.0.10
PC1 Network2 - 192.168.137.1

PC2 Network1 - 10.0.0.11

Server Network1 - 192.168.137.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Maybe this helps .](https://serverfault.com/questions/570439/setting-a-static-route-for-a-specific-network-adapter-with-two-network-adapters)

Something like this ...

route add -p 192.168.137.2 mask 255.255.255.0 10.0.0.10

Add a static route to the 192.168.137.2 network that uses a subnet mask of    255.255.255.0 and a gateway of 10.0.0.10

1. [Microsoft Route Tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757323(v=ws.10).aspx)